# Elasticsearch Restore from S3 Snapshot

Tags: elasticsearch, restore, snapshot, elasticsearch-snapshot

We are trying to Restore the snapshot from S3 bucket. The snapshot is taken from a different cluster (7.12) & getting restored in different cluster (7.17 ).

Below is the error during the restore activity

```
"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"process_cluster_event_timeout_exception","reason":"failed to process cluster event (add-block-index-to-close [[cib_/MAZVfK1fR2aQL2op_bMAhg]]) within 30s"}],"type":"process_cluster_event_timeout_exception","reason":"failed to process cluster event (add-block-index-to-close [[cib_/MAZVfK1fR2aQL2op_bMAhg]]) within 30s"},"status":503}
```

We are using an automation script to close the index & perform restore using below statements

```
curl -X POST -u admin:$passw "https://$HOST_NAME:9201/$index/_close"

      curl -X POST -u admin:$passw "https://$HOST_NAME:9201/_snapshot/$REPOSITORY_NAME/$snapshotname/_restore?wait_for_completion=true" -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d'
     {
      "indices": "'"$index"'",
      "ignore_unavailable": true,
      "include_global_state": false,
      "partial": false,
      "index_settings":{
      "index.routing.allocation.exclude.app": "someapp"
                       }
       }
      ' >> s3repo_cibrcdn.json
```

Can someone help about the error. We dont have any timeouts mentioned

Comment: There is indeed a timeout (i.e. "event could not be done within 30s"). This could be due to a number of reasons such as heavy load on the cluster, slow disk I/O, or network latency. If none of these apply to you, you can retry the restore operation by increasing the timeout `/_restore?timeout=60s`.

Comment: I believe this is `master_timeout` in that case no ?